# Shopify - how server knows the URL to be served

Tags: shopify

I am working on Shopify. I am trying to add business rules just before checkout. I can do that by introducing Javascript. But before I do that I had a question. Below is the HTML for checkout button.

```
<input type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn" value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}">
```

As you can see, there is no mention of URL or any javascript. So when checkout button is clicked, how does server know what to do. Also where can I find that particular code.

Also 'cart.general.checkout' is a variable to hold the text appearing on button. Where or which file should I refer to, if I want to change the default text.

Comment: shopify uses relative urls.

Comment: @miglio, thanks for reply. However, the logic to move forward ie to next page or move to previous page must be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the the input element inside a form, with an action set to /checkout. That is the magic sauce that tells the browser where to go. The server has nothing to do with button clicks. It renders the HTML, CSS and JS files, but it could care a less what happens when something gets clicked.

Comment: Thanks @David. I have checked the form tag and it doesn't mention /Checkout. Below is my form tag -    <form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="cart">

Comment: then find your listener to submit events and fix the destination there.

Comment: I tried to use chrome debugger and find the listener, but it took me to query.min.js which was too complex for me to understand. Hence I used a Jquery function and called event.preventDefault(); it worked for me. However, wanted to know if thats the correct way and safe too.